# Got error calling soap method with suds client

Tags: python, python-2.7, soap, suds, spyne

I have written a SOAP server using `Spyne` library of python 2.7. This is my server:

```
import logging
import random
import string
import json
from spyne.decorator import rpc
from spyne.application import Application
from spyne.service import ServiceBase
from spyne.model.primitive import Integer, String, Long
from spyne.server.wsgi import WsgiApplication
from spyne.protocol.soap import Soap11
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server

class merchantservicesSoap(ServiceBase):
    @rpc(Integer, String, Long, _returns=String)
    def CheckTransactionResult(ctx, merchantConfigurationID, encryptedCredentials, localInvoiceID):
    return json.dumps(
        {
            "Result": 500,
            "CardNumber": '-'.join([
                ''.join(random.sample(string.digits.replace('0', ''), 4)),
                '00' + ''.join(random.sample(string.digits, 2)),
                '0000',
                ''.join(random.sample(string.digits, 4))
            ]),
            "RRN": ''.join(random.sample(string.digits.replace('0', ''), 8)) * 2,
            "RefID": random.randint(10000, 500000),
            "Amount": random.randint(10000, 500000),
            "PayGateTranID": ''.join(random.sample(string.digits.replace('0', ''), 8)) * 2,
            "SalesOrderID": localInvoiceID
        }
    )


application = Application(
    [merchantservicesSoap],
    tns='http://tempuri.org/',
    in_protocol=Soap11(validator='lxml'),
    out_protocol=Soap11()
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    logging.getLogger('spyne.util').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    wsgi_app = WsgiApplication(application)
    server = make_server('0.0.0.0', 55555, wsgi_app)
    server.serve_forever()
```

I also have a client to call its methods, but I got an error. Here's my client:

```
import logging 
from suds.client import Client

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger('spyne.client').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

c = Client('http://127.0.0.1:55555/?wsdl')
print c.service.CheckTransactionResult(5, 'zizi', 8888)
```

And this is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 9, in <module>
    print c.service.CheckTransactionResult(5, 'zizi', 8888)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/client.py", line 542, in __call__
    return client.invoke(args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/client.py", line 602, in invoke
    result = self.send(soapenv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/client.py", line 649, in send
    result = self.failed(binding, e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/client.py", line 702, in failed
    r, p = binding.get_fault(reply)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds/bindings/binding.py", line 265, in get_fault
    raise WebFault(p, faultroot)
suds.WebFault: Server raised fault: 'Internal Error'
```

I've set some break-points and I realized that the request does not reach the server at all; which means there is something wrong with my request that doesn't meet the server prototypes. But as far as I know, the client request has met definitions; am I missing something here?

Comment: Can you also put the traceback from the server side?

Comment: @BurakArslan, thanks for your attention. I have solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The error disappeared after I restarted my server with a new listening port. It seems there was some caching issue.